# Animate dispatch markers on Mapbox

Tags: ios, animation, mapbox, markerclusterer

On Mapbox I have clustered markers on my map. When I zoom the dispatch work but without any position animation.

Is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This capability isn't built into the SDK, but you might be able to do it with animations yourself. Have a look at the `RMQuadTree` class, which manages the clusters, and then consider showing the animation by transitioning between the clustered and unclustered state.